# Hover over svg does not work when mouse is over text within the svg item

Tags: css, svg, sass, hover

I wanted to apply a simple hover over both the shape and text inside it. It's supposed to change the color (in this case fill), when pointer is over either the shape or the text. I thought that if the text is kind of inside of the svg element, the hover will be applied to it too. Except it isn't.

I'm not good with svg, in fact, this is the first time I'm working with them. Tried to find answers here and in google, but nothing applies to my problem. Please help.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 900 170">
      <path class="a" fill={funnels[funnel].bgColor} d="M378.24,59.8l33.39,88.73a11.82,11.82,0,0,0,11.07,7.66h54.6a11.82,11.82,0,0,0,11.07-7.66L521.76,59.8a11.82,11.82,0,0,0-11.07-16H389.31A11.82,11.82,0,0,0,378.24,59.8Z"></path>
      <text x="50%" y="60%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Lato" font-size="2rem" fill="#f2f2f2"> Hello </text>
    </svg>


svg {
      filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));

      .a {
        transition: all ease-in 0.5s;

        &:hover {
          fill: darken(red, 10%);
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Madzik/bkbgf1os/

Answer (score 1):

Apply hover effect to `svg` not `.a`.

```
svg {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));

  .a {
    transition: all ease-in 0.5s;
  }

  &:hover {
    fill: darken(red, 10%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
}

svg .a {
  transition: all ease-in 0.5s;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 900 170">
  <path class="a" fill={funnels[funnel].bgColor} d="M378.24,59.8l33.39,88.73a11.82,11.82,0,0,0,11.07,7.66h54.6a11.82,11.82,0,0,0,11.07-7.66L521.76,59.8a11.82,11.82,0,0,0-11.07-16H389.31A11.82,11.82,0,0,0,378.24,59.8Z"></path>
  <text x="50%" y="60%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Lato" font-size="2rem" fill="#f2f2f2"> Hello </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I did that but then the pointer:cursor is on the whole area that the svg element takes, which is far beyond the image itself.

Comment: Because you didn't set the size of svg. You should set width and height of this element.

Comment: I added the svg size, but it doesn't change anything. The pointer is still visible on the whole svg area, not the path.
I think you want me to make the svg smaller, the problem is that I have several elements (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/Madzik/bkbgf1os/) , all of them have different sizes, the biggest one is almost equal to the viewbox. I want them to have the same viewbox to maintain the relative dimensions. Is there any way to make the text hoverable and the viewbox not hoverable except for the path? Or any workaround?

Comment: There are two problems: Css doesn't have `prev element` selector,  so you can not say "Hey css, fill path element with red when I hover text element." And second problem is that text element is placed over path element. And when you hover text, path losses hover effect. You can add `pointer-events: none;` to text. and this element will be "transparent" for all actions. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/